# How to install .net dll?

Tags: .net, dll

In visual studio, when user Add Reference, another dialog box will be pop out and showing a list of .net component. I try to copy a dll into GAC folder but I don't know how to make that dll appear in the Add Reference dialog box. Anyone know why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to make sure your dll is located in the Visual Studio public assemblies folder, or that its folder location is known by some specific Visual Studio registry keys.  For further information, and the specific locations of folder and settings refer to the following url:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx

The reason that Visual Studio needs to know specifically where all dlls live is probably to try and improve the performance of the very slow Add References dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't plan to use this dll in any other application it is not necessary to install it as a shared dll in GAC. Just go to the browse tab on the add reference's pop up and search the folder where you build your assembly (the Debug or Release folder inside the project).

If you still think you need this dll to be shared, you have to set a strong name for it first. Follow this link for instructions:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1950-Install-an-Assembly-GAC-Global-Assembly-Cache.aspx